# Title in latin with label after the name

Tags: titles, chapters

I am typing a critical edition with translation using reledmac and reledpar.
How can I type the titles of the original edition (in latin) so that the name of the title (of a chapter) comes first and then, in another line, the label (that's how the manuscript has it), say:

```
Potiora loca maritima totius Germaniae
Caput undecimum
```

I need this to be typed like that both in the text and in the TOC.
Note that the name of the chapter must be in latin and the labell in latin and in full (I suppose babel achieves partially this: firts it doesn't sort things on the order I want; second it doesn't type the label in full, say, caput primum, secundum, decimum, uicesimum...).
Thanks a lot for your help.

The code provided bellow by Christian Hupfer is perfect, but I made some adjustments and I have some more doubts.

Among the many things I don’t have a clue what they mean in the code there is the   zerum% (I won’t use use it, but it is better to learn why is it there)  Anyway I have to use ordinals and not cardinals, so I have changed the code accordingly (ordinals in the neuter because of *caput*):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\thechapternumberformat}{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}
  zerum%
  \or
  primum%
  \or
  secundum%
  \or
  tertium%
  \or
  quartum%
  \or
  quintum%
  \or
  sextum%
  \or
  septimum%
  \or
  octauum%
  \or
  nonum%
  \or
  decimum%
  \or
  undecimum%
  \or
  duodecimum%
  \fi
}


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapternumberformat
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{ What have the Romans ever done for us?}


\blindtext

\chapter{Quid sit informationis technologia}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I’ve changed the horizontal alignment, though I sense the outcome may be awful sometimes (many words in the title resulting in one word hanging). The problem is that a chapter in an old text isn’t the same as a chapter in a modern book. Sometimes it is a tiny chunk of text but they call it a chapter. The fact that chapters are very small asks for a more compact layout. Something like [this edition](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pPJPhOnv7lwC&lpg=PR1&dq=Italy%20illuminated%20Hankins&hl=pt-PT&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q=Florentia&f=false) of The I Tatti Renaissance Library.

Some my final doubt, where can I adjust the vertical space between the chapter title and the following text (I want to reduce it). My text has approximately 15 000 words but 26 chapters (an average of 576 words per chapter). That is why I need to have the chapter title closer to the text.

Comment: So you want *chapter one*, *chapter two*, *chapter three*, but in latin?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of your skeleton document? class, babel is titlesec used?

Comment: `\usepackage[latin]{babel}` will at least provide the correct names for `chapter` etc. However, the Latin numbers are not provided by a package, as far as I know

Comment: Welcome :) I'm not sure your edit was really appropriate. It's really important to view this site as a Q & A site, with a question at the top and answers to that question at the bottom, rather than something like a forum where you may have a thread to yourself to ask questions and follow-up questions and go back and forth. If you have more questions, you should ask them separately. Asking about others' code is best done as a separate question, or in the comments beneath their answer, although I understand you don't have enough rep to comment on any post yet.

Comment: Also mildly tweaking somebody else's work and then adding it back into your own question doesn't really make a lot of sense. If you've made a substantial edit that makes the answer a better answer to the question asked, you can add a new answer, giving all appropriate credit. If you've made just minor edits, it would be better to leave a comment to the answer, or edit the answer. If you've tweaked something to make it better suit your needs, but the change doesn't address the actual question, best keep it to yourself.

Comment: In any case, editing an answer into the question itself really isn't something that makes sense here, however, providing an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is *always* important, so the most up-to-date version of your code (which will obviously be similar or identical to the answer) does belong in any new, follow-up question. Sorry, not a rant, just some pointers, the SE format can easily trip people up. Once again, welcome! :)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn’t post a comment so long (there is a limit of characters, I realized). I still have to learn how to make a follow-up question...

Comment: @Sintram Just ask a new question, exactly the same way you asked this one. It's best if you include a link to this question. Also there is a balance to be struck, it is important to make sure the new question is, well, new and different, and the right approach in some cases is to edit the original question to add more details or something like that. But adding new questions into an existing question is a bad idea partly because, in all cases, you should only have one question at a time, and partly because people are less likely to see it.

Comment: You'll also be consistently invalidating - or, at least, undermining - any existing answers, which won't address all the new points. But don't get me wrong, sometimes you get an answer and you realise you hadn't framed the question properly and the answer doesn't work for you because you're using this package, or you also have that requirement, and you have to make an edit to nail the question down - that is fine :)

Answer (score 3):

My knowledge of Latin has decently during the last decades... Please apologize for any error in the language ;-)

`babel` has settings for Latin and uses the correct translations then, however, the numbers written as words are not provided neither by `babel` nor by `fmtcount`.

I've provided a small workaround for the numbers from 1 to 12 at least.

In order to switch the order of chapter name and chapter number, I've changed the `\@makechapterhead` command, as an example with `book.cls`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\thechapternumberformat}{%
  \ifcase\value{chapter}%
  zerum%
  \or
  unum%
  \or
  duo%
  \or
  tria%
  \or
  quattuor%
  \or
  quinque%
  \or
  sex%
  \or
  septem%
  \or
  octo%
  \or
  novem%
  \or
  decem%
  \or
  undecim%
  \or
  duodecim%
  \fi
}


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapternumberformat
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{What have the Romans ever done for us?}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect with some tuning more. Among the many things I don’t have a clue what they mean in the code there is the   zerum% (I won’t use use it, but it is better to learn why is it there)  Anyway I have to use ordinals and not cardinals, so I change the code:

Comment: The aqueduct? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: No, the aqueduck -t :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: ooh `:)`

Comment: @Sintram https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/0 says the Latin word is “often *zerus*”; of course it's a new formation, as classical Latin hadn't it.